# Target specific slide in Soliloquy slider with url

Tags: slider

Does anyone have any experience with using a url to target a specific slide in a Soliloquy slider? I am using multiple sliders that I need to link to specific slides of from external pages/sites. The Soliloquy Docs provide this info (soliloquywp.com/docs/dynamically-set-the-starting-slide/) as closest to the solution but, for a php noob like me, the explanation is a bit terse and lacking, my fault, not theirs.

The example given in the docs seems to be a custom filter for a specific slide in a specific slider. I need to target slides in multiple sliders with urls. I guess I need help understanding the filter's function. I have commented out what I think each part does. Maybe someone could show me where I'm wrong?

```
//OP: I don't understand, what ids/slides are represented by the 10 and 2 values in these parameters. Where do I find these?
add_filter( 'soliloquy_pre_data', 'tgm_soliloquy_dynamic_starting_slide', 10, 2 );
function tgm_soliloquy_dynamic_starting_slide( $data, $slider_id ) {
// If the proper $_GET parameter is not set or is not the proper slider ID, do nothing.
//OP: Is the 'sol_slide' parameter for ALL soliloquy sliders in my site or is it the name in the Dashboard given when constructing the slider?
if ( empty( $_GET['sol_slide'] ) ) {
return $data;
}
// Change this if you want to target a specific slider ID, or remove altogether if you want this for all sliders.
//OP: I believe to target ALL sliders in my site I should comment this out. Right?
if ( 51064 !== $slider_id ) {
return $data;
}
// Set the slide number as a config property. Also preventing randomizing slides.
$data['config']['start'] = absint( $_GET['sol_slide'] );
$data['config']['random'] = 0;
// Optionally prevent autostarting the slider. Uncomment if you want that.
//$data['config']['auto'] = 0;
return $data;
}
```

Basically, I guess I am asking for a little help with implementing this filter to target any slide in any slider with a url. Slim odds, but I'm dead in the water! Big thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Complete, correctly functioning answer is here: http://soliloquywp.com/support/topic/a-way-to-link-directly-to-a-specific-slide/

Answer (score 0):

Complete, correctly functioning answer is here provided the plugin author, of course, duh: http://soliloquywp.com/support/topic/a-way-to-link-directly-to-a-specific-slide/

The value "sol_slide" is generic to any slider created with the plugin. Just put the custom filter provided in the example into your, hopefully, child-theme's functions.php, and construct your urls targeting specific slides like so: http://mywebsite.com/specific-product-page-with-slider/?sol_slide=3. Slide numbering is based on zero so 1 = 2 etc. Works like a charm.